# Much more or a Lot more

Tags: grammar, word-usage

So I was talking to someone and I said the next :" that would be a lot more appropriate"  , the other person corrected me and said that I should say "much more appropriate"  . So I was wondering if I'm wrong ,  both of them are correct  or is there a rule that I should be following here ?

Answer (score 1):

I would generally tend to think that "a lot" v "much" corresponds to the "fewer"/"less" debate. We know those grocery store signs should actually say "x items or fewer," given that the word "fewer" implies a countable number--presumably, you could count the number of items in your cart; likewise, if you have 10x the maximum number of items, I would say you have "a lot" in your cart--not "much" in your cart!

Thus, because you can't talk about the quantity of appropriateness of something, but rather the quality of it (per your example), one would say, "that would be much more appropriate."

Comment: +1 for identifying a framework to think about this. However, 'a lot' can be used for non-countables as well. Consider *a lot* vs *a little*.

Answer (score -2):

" A lot" is  colloquial.  It is acceptable in informal speech, but not in formal writing.

Comment: Answers are expected to be lengthy. A good expert answer includes explanation, context, and supporting facts. This is what makes the answer useful – not only to the asker, but to future visitors to the page. Please consider expanding your answer.